# Do Spellcaster Class DCs not increase?

Tags: spellcasting, difficulty-class, pathfinder-2e

This feels like a stupid question, but I can't find any actual answers.

While building a higher-level character to play with the system a little, I noticed what appears to be an omission. At some point in each class's progression, the Class DC will increase incrementally. For example:

> **Mighty Rage** Barbarian lvl 11th
>
> Your rage intensifies and lets you burst into action. Your
> proficiency rank for your barbarian class DC increases
> to expert. You gain the Mighty Rage free action.

But in the spellcasting classes, the Class DC is not explicitly mentioned in what appears to be the appropriate feats. For example:

> **Expert Spellcaster** Wizard lvl 7th
>
> Extended practice of the arcane has improved your
> capabilities. Your proficiency ranks for arcane spell
> attack rolls and spell DCs increase to expert.

Is this a weird omission in the actual writing? Or am I completely misunderstanding the way Class DCs work, and the spellcasting classes *just* use their Spell DC instead of the Class DC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## The latter

Spellcasters call their "class DC" "spell DC"; those two are equivalent in any way that I have seen.

I have not found any class abilities for spellcasters that call for a "class DC", so indeed, I think you have misunderstood class DC slightly.

Answer (score 12):

## Most spellcasters' class DCs do not increase

The Remaster made it clear that *class DC* and *spell DC* are not the same by listing them separately, see page 193 of the Player Core.

Full casters like the Wizard do not increase their *class DC*.