# Do casters become experts with Class DC?

Tags: pathfinder-2e, class

Some things, like weapon critical effects, reference your class DC, but most casters do not list a class DC progression.

It would however be interesting for example for a Magus using [Arcane Fists](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3033), as a critical hit with a [brawling](https://2e.aonprd.com/WeaponGroups.aspx?ID=4) weapon calls for Fort save against your class DC to avoid *slowed 1*.

Instinctively we have been using the spell DC, because for most classes that have bot (Champions for example) these move together, but recently we discovered that it is against the rules.

[The only rule I could find](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=137) states that everyone has it, but does it increase for a Magus?

(Magus is just an example, a Psion could also be using an ancestral weapon with the 5th level feat or an [Owlbear Claw](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=230))

Comment: Essentially, I am looking for a rule that says spell DC is your class DC if you do not have one specifically

Comment: Can you clarify how the rule you cite means that everyone ist trained in their class DC?

Comment: @Patta, link edited

Comment: I still don't see where that says anything about your proficiency, tbh.

Comment: You are right, it was mainly wishful thinking. Still, it seems it is what the designers _meant_

Comment: The essence of this question is the same as [this other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159300/4576). Is there anything to differentiate it?

Comment: @PD-whee-whim-wish, it is the same, however the answer there is wrong

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Most casters are Untrained in Class DC

Class DC and Spell DC are separate, there is no general rule equating them or making them interchangeable. Certain feats and features specify the greater of the two, like [Kobold Breath](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=1272). Some classes are trained in both, like Champion, and sometimes Monk and Ranger. If the class description does not specify proficiency in Class DC, then it is Untrained.

Comment: They will be trained in 4 days