# What game elements use class DC only?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

While writing [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205330/do-casters-become-experts-with-class-dc), I tried to find some things beside weapon criticals that list class DC only, but no spell DCs.

Archetypes typically use both ([Mind Smith](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3867)):

> You concentrate and unleash a 15-foot cone that deals 3d6 mental damage to all creatures in the area, with a *basic Will save against the **higher of your class DC or spell DC***

Ancestries too ([Nagaji](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3987)):

> The target must attempt a *Will save against the **higher of your class DC or spell DC***

Obviously, I do not mean class features and [class feats](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3721), when they are tied to a class without spell DC, they only use the class DC.

**Does any widely usable thing beside weapon critical specialization effects use your class DC, but not your spell DC?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking over feats (manually) from [this search](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=class%20DC&include-traits=all%20ancestries%3Barchetype%3Bgeneral%3Bskill&traits-operator=or&display=list):

- From [Martial Artist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Archetypes.aspx?ID=67):

  - [Black Powder Flash](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3572)
  - [Thunder Clap](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3576)
  - [Mountain Quake](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=474&ArchLevel=16)
- (Quest for the Frozen Flame Spoiler) [Game Hunter Dedication](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3425)
- (Outlaws of Alkenstar Spoiler) [Loose Cannon from Alkenstar Agent](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3569)
- [Desiccating Inhalation from Mummy](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3530)
- [Roadkill from Trick Driver](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=3145)
- (Abomination Vaults Spoiler) [Lethargy Poisoner from Drow Shootist](https://2e.aonprd.com/Feats.aspx?ID=2686)

Looking over items from [this search](https://2e.aonprd.com/Search.aspx?q=%22class%20DC%22&type=eqs&include-types=item&display=list):

- [Thundercrasher](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=1894) (a magic blunderbluss)
- A couple of [Blighted Boons](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?Category=104):

  - [Void Fragment](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2373)
  - [Heartblood Ring](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=2371)